# Laravel 2 api integration

Tags: laravel, api, integration, laravel-passport

I need to integrate 2 api with each other.Can i use laravel passport for this? My first api generate secret, second api use this token in every request ang getting user data by secret. I didn't find a solution for this in the laravel passport. Seem to be it only provides authorization via oauth2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is web tokens as opposed to oauth.

You need to use jwt for this:

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

Andrew Schmelyun on youtube shows you how to do this easily :

[Securing a Laravel API in 20 minutes with JWTs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eX9Pj-GhZs)

Update: Alternatively you can also use Laravel Sanctum for simple SPAs:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: Thank you, I also think, but at work they ask through a laravel / passport. And I don't understand how to do it. I tried everything

Comment: Ok, in that case, you cannot use web tokens the way you have explained it in the question. You have no choice but to use OAuth2 using Laravel Passport and explain to them that you cannot use web tokens. Its either JWT or Laravel Sanctum which is another you can use